# Angular, dynamic directive load, and event management

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Context**

I m actually developping an application in which I need to generate directive dynamically from a controller to a view (drag n drop system).

It works like this :

*the directive*

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
                    ele.html(html);
                    $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

*And in the controller, it looks like :*

```
$scope.listModules = [
            {libelle: "Utilisateurs connectés", template: "<div user-connecte></div>", drag: true}
]
```

*And in the HTML file :*

```
<div ng-repeat="currentModule in listModules" dynamic="currentModule.template">
The directive loaded
</div>
```

**The problem**

I want to use the

```
$scope.$emit('event');
```

from my controller, to send some information to my directive, which is supposed to get it with :

```
$scope.$on('event',function(){console.log('yiihaaa');})
```

It seems that it doesnt happen anything...

I need the log to be displayed.

Can you help me ?

Thanks for advance

Comment: how you try `emit`? `ngRepeat` create isolate scope, so possibly `$broadcast` is what you need

Comment: In a function in controller on a ng-click :  $scope.rechercherStats = function () {
            $scope.$emit('reload');
        };

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: It's a complex function actually. I try to make it simpler

Comment: in your OP not used `ng-click`, so unclear how all working

Comment: sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YFqFKQtQN0KWptOWIl86?p=preview) if someone needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngRepeate` create own isolated scope, and *scope* in your directive link function is this isolated scope.

When you do [`$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit)

> Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered $rootScope.Scope listeners.

For sending event to child scopes you need use [$broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast)

So for solving your problem you have at least two ways

1) use *$broadcast* instead of *$emit*

```
$scope.rechercherStats = function () { $scope.$broadcast('reload'); };
```

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('app',[])
       .controller('ctrl',function($scope){
         $scope.listModules = [
            {libelle: "Utilisateurs connectés", template: "<div user-connecte></div>", drag: true}
];
$scope.rechercherStats = function () {console.log('reload'); $scope.$broadcast('reload'); };

       });
angular.module('app')
    .directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
                    ele.html(html);
                    $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                });
                scope.$on('reload',function(){console.log('yiihaaa');})

            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
Sample    
    <div ng-repeat="currentModule in listModules" dynamic="currentModule.template">
The directive loaded
</div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="rechercherStats()" value="btn"/>
    </div>
```

2) add listener not in scope ngRepeat, but in parent scope

```
angular.module('app')
       .directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
           return {
               restrict: 'A',
               replace: true,
               link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                   scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
                       ele.html(html);
                       $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                   });
                   scope.$parent.on('event',function(){console.log('yiihaaa');});
               }
           };
      });
```

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('app',[])
       .controller('ctrl',function($scope){
         $scope.listModules = [
            {libelle: "Utilisateurs connectés", template: "<div user-connecte></div>", drag: true}
];
$scope.rechercherStats = function () {console.log('reload'); $scope.$emit('reload'); };

       });
angular.module('app')
    .directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function (html) {
                    ele.html(html);
                    $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
                });
                scope.$parent.$on('reload',function(){console.log('yiihaaa');})

            }
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
Sample    
    <div ng-repeat="currentModule in listModules" dynamic="currentModule.template">
The directive loaded
</div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="rechercherStats()" value="btn"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Grundy said. Use *$broadcast* and *$on* from *$rootScope*.

```
var subscription = $rootScope.$on("myEvent", function() {
    console.log("yiihao");
});
```

Don't forget to destroy it.

```
$rootScope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    subscription();
});
```

The *$broadcast* would be like that.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("myEvent", {});
```

Comment: `$rootScope` not needed :-) simple scope enough

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this link: http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/

They are loading directives on the fly. The approach can be adapted for your requirements?